# On/Off haptic feedback Switch (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, haptic-feedback

I have SettingsVC ("Photo" there are 2 switch) and MainVC ("Code" there is a function for adding haptic feedback buttons).

How can I make it so that when you turn off the Switch in Setting, then the function would stop working?

[SettingsVC "Photo"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJXaW.png)

```
@IBAction func Vib(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let generator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .light)
    generator.impactOccurred()
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can store the switch state in `UserDefaults` and then check for it in your function.

**In your switch action:**

```
@IBAction func switchAction(sender: UISwitch) { 
    if sender.isOn {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "SwitchState")
    } else {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "SwitchState")
    }
}
```

**In your MainVC func**

```
@IBAction func Vib(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: “SwitchState”) else { return }

    let generator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .light)
    generator.impactOccurred()
}
```

Comment: There's no need to compare a boolean to true. You can get rid of this `== true`

Comment: @FrancescoDeliro my function is always switched off when using your code and is always on Switch.

Comment: Your switch default state isOn? And if you change switch value to off and then to on try to make a print of UserDefaults Bool value.